# foreach in php class returns only 1 result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, return

I've the following code:

**Example.class.php**

```
class Example {
    public function functionArrayExample() {
        $query = array();

        // this foreach comes from a select that returns more than 1 results
        foreach($someSelect as $exAS) {
            $query[] = $exAS;
        }

        return $query;
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once("Example.class.php");

$example = new Example();

$selectExample = $example -> functionArrayExample();

die(var_dump($selectExample));
```

But, only 1 result (in array) is showed (in `die()` line), why? Since the query returns more than 1 result?

Comment: Can you show us the SELECT statement and how it is used to give the `$someSelect` array?

Comment: you need to specify what is you `$someSelect` variable, because it is not obvious from the example.

Comment: Also can you post the code on how you are retrieving the rows from the query?

Comment: What is the value of `count($someSelect)`?

Comment: Where does `$someSelect` come from?????????? Its not passed as a parameter? Its not created from a query? You dont use `$this->` In other words **it does not exist**

Comment: The select query is correctly, because in other function with same select is returned 2 results

Answer (score 1):

If I add:

```
    $someSelect = array();
    $someSelect[] = 'red';
    $someSelect[] = 'blue';
    $someSelect[] = 'green';
```

above the `foreach($someSelect as $exAS) {` then your code works perfectly.

So, your error must be with your `$someSelect` array.

Comment: Exactly... there is nothing wrong with the foreach statement which means the problem is in the code that isn't provided, making the question useless.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved the problem: the `return` returned only 1 result (and I don't know why) but with `print_r` the results returned correctly (2 results in array).